# Minor graphics branding issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "develop yourself" careers graphic is still using the old "6-leaf" stack icon.

[image]

Comment: Wow you've got an awesome sight. No wonder you are a mod, who's gotta keep an *eye on bad stuff* :D

Comment: @BhargavRao or maybe you've seen the correct one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah yes. An old ad. With an old Careers logo as well! (The Careers wordmark was moved to be underneath Stack Overflow with our recent brand update, as you can see in the new artwork below.) We've been phasing these out. We did update this ad but this older version apparently *did not want to die.* Thanks for alerting us.

The new one looks like this:

[image: Develop Yourself]

Comment: Hmmm... looked better with the full stop after "develop yourself", I think. Nice one on the font change though.

Comment: I also think that there is too much space between "develop" and "yourself".

Comment: @Thunderforge It's a monospaced font. That's a typical space.

Comment: Monospaced or not, it still looks a bit unattractive to me. But that's just my thoughts.